# Awk - return nth word in a column starting with pattern

Tags: linux, awk

I know I can use awk to get a line starting with expression `exp` by `awk '/^exp/'`. How do I get the n-th word from this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try:

```
awk -v n="$var" '/^exp/{print $n}' file
```

`$var` could be shell variable, the value is the index of your column.

Answer (score 3):

Use {print $n} in the awk statement

```
echo "abcd bcd cd d" | awk '/^ab/ { print $3}'
```

This would echo "cd"

Answer (score 1):

`awk '{print $n}'` to print out the nth word in the line ?